# Python sendto telling me it needs an int

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

```
from socket import *
import packets
image = "testfile.bmp"

# open image
bufferSize = 2048
myfile = open(image, 'rb')
sequenceNumber = 0
totalBytes = 0

serverName = "127.0.0.1"
serverSendPort = 12000
serverSendPort = int(serverSendPort)
serverListenPort = 12001
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

while (1):
    if (sequenceNumber == 0):
        data = packets.mkepckt(myfile.read(bufferSize), 0,         
packets.calculateChecksum(myfile.read(bufferSize), bufferSize))
        clientSocket.sendto(bytearray(data),(serverName, serverSendPort))
        sequenceNumber = 1

        ACK,  = serverSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
        ACKchecksum = packets.calculateChecksum(ACK[1], bufferSize)

        while (ACK[0] is not 0 or ACKchecksum is not ACK[2]):
            clientSocket.sendto(data, (serverName, serverSendPort))
            ACK,  = serverSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
            ACKchecksum = packets.calculateChecksum(ACK[1], bufferSize)

    elif (sequenceNumber == 1):
        data = packets.mkepckt(myfile.read(bufferSize), 1,     
packets.calculateChecksum(myfile.read(bufferSize), bufferSize))
        clientSocket.sendto(bytearray(data),(serverName, serverSendPort))
        sequenceNumber = 0

        ACK,  = serverSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
        ACKchecksum = packets.checksum(bufferSize, ACK[1])

        while (ACK[0] is not 1 or ACKchecksum is not ACK[2]):
            clientSocket.sendto(data, (serverName, serverSendPort))
            ACK,  = serverSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
            ACKchecksum = packets.calculateChecksum(ACK[1], bufferSize)

myfile.close()

clientSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

Not sure I needed to put my whole code, but better safe than sorry.
So for some reason, despite the fact that I have an int in the sendto. I have also tried all sorts of typecasting, from typecasting each individual element to typecasting the whole thing as an int, and I still get this error.

Comment: What is the EXACT error message? Your calls to `sendto()` are inconsistent, though. Some of them are passing `data` directly, while others are passing `bytearray(data)` instead.

Comment: The first error I got was that "TypeError("a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'")", so I changed I typecasted the first one, but I must have forgotten to typecast the rest. As for the exact error: "TypeError('an integer is required')"

Comment: I'm no Python expert (I'm not even a Python *user*), but your calls to `sendto()` look OK to me. What kind of object is `mkepckt()` returning exactly? Are you sure it is a byte array? Also, your calls to `calculateChecksum()` when calling `mkepckt()` look suspiciously wrong to me. You are calling `myfile.read()` twice, so you are passing different bytes to `mkepckt()` and `calculateChecksum()`. Shouldn't you be passing the same bytes to both? Something like: `data = myfile.read(bufferSize) data = packets.mkepckt(data, 0, packets.calculateChecksum(data, len(data)))`

Comment: Also, when calling `calculateChecksum()` after `recvfrom()`, shouldn't you be using `len(ACK)` instead of `BufferSize`? Passing `BufferSize` to `recvfrom()` is the *maximum* number of bytes to read, but that is no guarantee that is the number of bytes *actually* read, it may be less.

Comment: Make packet is a tuple. It really just takes all those objects and adds them together into a local variable then returns it. I mostly did it this way so I can have all my "packet" functions in one file, to keep things clean.

As for those other two things, I believe you are absolutely correct. I have changed them, thanks. Still getting that int error though, not sure what to do about it.

Comment: "*Make packet is a tuple*" - AFAIK, you can't pass a tuple to the 1st parameter of `sendto()`, only a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from @RemyLebeau, I was able to solve this problem by importing pickle and using that to dump my tuple into a variable, then sending that variable as the data. Not sure why the byte data gave off an error about an int, but there you go.